# is there a way to link static library in Cmakelist file?

Tags: cmakelists-options, target-link-libraries

## **Can anyone recommend a best way to link a third-party static library to a source file?**

I am trying to link .a static binary library file to my source file.  I have tried everything adding it json as an arg[] and adding to CMake, like other people have recommended, but some reason it is failing.

I am not sure what is the next option.

Thanks for your help in advance.!

I have tried several different options.

Option: 1

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L1pZp.png)

Option: 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1v0B1.png)

Option: 3

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nxCZK.png)

Here is the Error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H0NtN.png)

Here is the picture of my project tree:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hSif.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please post all code and output examples in code blocks in the question — not screenshots. Each question should include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)